# Fading Tabs with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am currently using this function to add and remove classes which shows and hides my tabs perfectly.  I would like to elaborate on this so the contents fade in...

**Here is my HTML**

```
<ul id='tabs'>
    <li class='current'>
        <a class='tabLink' href='#'>Title</a>
        <div class='tabInfo'>
            <p>Text Description</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class='tabLink' href='#'>Title</a>
        <div class='tabInfo'>
            <p>Text Description</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**And my JS**

```
$('a.tabLink').click(function(){
    $tabs.removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
});
```

**AND CSS**

```
#tabs {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}
a.tabLink {
    color: #58585A;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
a.tabLink:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tabInfo {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 176px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
.current .tabLink {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
}
.current .tabInfo {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I assume `$tabs` contains all of the `li` elements?

Comment: $(this).next().fadeIn('<speed>')

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how your CSS looks, but this might work.

```
$('a.tabLink').click(function(){
      $(".tabInfo", $tabs)
        .stop().fadeOut("slow", function() { //Fadeout old content
          $tabs.removeClass('current');
          $(this).parent().addClass('current');
          $(this).next(".tabLink").fadeIn();
      });
});
```

Comment: This fades out all my tabs :) and links :)

Comment: Nope this kills them all together :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.tabLink').click(function(){
    $tabs.removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    $(this).parent().find('.tabInfo').fadeIn();
});
```

If i understand correctly, you want to fade the content in. If the content is hidden, which it appears it would be, using a fadeIn() on the tabInfo div would be appropriate.

Comment: His code should work if you remove/disable the `.current .tabInfo` style rule.

Comment: H Daniel, it didnt work, it only displayed the ul li not the the actual info

Comment: Oh! There's a bug in the last line of the click event-handler. The selector is missing a pretty critical `.`; the line should read `$(this).parent().find('.tabInfo').fadeIn();`.

Comment: hah! good catch, i hadn't noticed that, you are absolutely correct, that will probably make it work for him, editing it for correctness

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by loading the jQuery UI library, and adding a second argument to your `addClass` invokation, the duration of the animation.

```
$('a.tabLink').click(function(){
    // the style effects will be applied over a period of one second
    $tabs.removeClass('current',1000);
    $(this).parent().addClass('current',1000);
});
```

See also: [the `addClass` page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/) of the jQuery UI documentation.

Comment: This doesn't change anything either sorry!

Comment: Have you included the jQuery UI library on your pages, in addition to the basic jQuery library?

Comment: No but i wouldn't want to for a small fade transition.

Comment: But i see what you mean sorry, i didnt realise yours relied on that.

Comment: Thanks though daniel for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.tabLink').click(function(){
    $tabs.removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    $(this).next().fadeIn()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the class current to the parent, you'll need to fade in the appropriate tabInfo.

```
$('a.tabLink').click(function(e){
  $('.tabInfo').css('display','none');
  $(this).parent().find('.tabInfo').fadeIn();
});
```